# Paypal integration, is possible multiple shop and multiple employee payout with single transaction?

Tags: express, paypal

I searched a solution for integrate Paypal to my app, but I not found ideal solution for my use case. I have multiple shop and employee in my platform. It is possible to the shop make payout to multiple employees in single transaction without I store paypal secret and paypal client id of shop?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. You'll need the equivalent of the client ID and secret to use the Payouts API, and each account that is going to send Payouts will need to be approved, per https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites/#get-access-to-paypal-payouts